# Bind Monit to use Port 443

Tags: linux, ubuntu, https, monit

I'm using Monit with this config:

```
set httpd port 2812
    allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
    allow md5 /etc/apache2/.htpasswd USERX
    ssl enable
    pemfile /etc/monit/pemfile-DOMAIN.pem
```

I can't change to port to 443 nor 80 but **I just want to use https on 443.**
I'm getting this error if I try:

```
[CEST Apr 26 23:08:33] error    : Cannot listen -- Address already in use
[CEST Apr 26 23:08:33] error    : HTTP server: not available -- could not create a server socket at port 443 -- Address already in use
```

Comment: Error seems clear? Address in use?

Comment: Yes of cause you're right, but Apache will always listen on 443 (I have some other domains running). It seems like there's no way to run it on 443?

Comment: Don't listen on port 443. Just listen on any other free port. Why do you want it on that port anyway?

Comment: I don't want to add a port when entering the URL. I  just want to use https://monit.domain.com. But I think I see the problem with Apache.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot listen on port 443 if already used by Apache.

You should bind Monit to another port (say, 8443).

If you don't want to type the domain with the port, that's fine. You should have a look at mod_proxy from Apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html

Basically, make Apache listen for `monit.example.com` on port 443, and forward those requests to localhost on port 8443 (where Monit is actually running).